# "A group leader" or "the group leader"?

Tags: grammar, nouns, articles

When I have an expression comprising two nouns does the article (*a*/*an*/*the*) refer to the first or to the second one? E.g. when talking about some group (we introduced it, there's only one), we would use *the* when referring to the group but then we also introduce someone being the leader of the group:

> ...there are at least 10 people in **the** group. However, if there's **a** group leader, we'd have to...

And even when I write that, I lean towards the *a* version as it just sounds natural to me. So that would mean the article refers to the 2nd noun (being the main object) and not the 1st one (acting as an epithet here). But is that correct? Is that always the case?

Comment: 'Group' here is being used to modify (add further information about the referent of) the noun 'leader'; the article or other determiner corresponds to the head noun. Thus 'several football managers'.

Answer (score 1):

> ...there are at least 10 people in the group. However, if there's **a** group leader, we'd have to...

In the first sentence, the word **group** is a noun. In the second sentence, it's used as an adjective: a "[noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)". Thus, the indefinite article **a** modifies the noun word **leader**.

You can remodel the sentence to make the word **group** a noun in the second sentence:

> However, if there is **a** leader in **the** group, we'd have to..

Now, you do need the definite article before **group**.

Per Barmar's comment, you can omit the word **group** from the second sentence altogether:

> ...there are at least 10 people in **the** group. However, if there's **a** leader, we'd have to...

The reference to the group would be then implicit.

Comment: Notice also that the word _group_ can even be omitted from the second sentence: _if there's a leader..._. The reference to the group is implicit.